# Moodle Course Total Grade

Tags: moodle

I want to display Course Total Grades like this:

if Quiz total = 1 then Course Total = 74

if Quiz total = 2 then Course Total = 74 again

if Quiz total = 3 then Course Total = 74 again

if Quiz total = 4 then Course Total = 77

if Quiz total = 5 then Course Total = 80

if Quiz total = 6 then Course Total = 83

...... and so on until Quiz total  =34

I can't think of any formula that can give me the desired result.

Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Can I change anything in the code maybe?

Comment: how do you get the course total for each quiz total value ? is it the result of a formula or an arbitrary value ?

Comment: there is no formula, the grades must be given according to the quiz number of correct answers, according to the above table, meaning if the quiz correct answer is 1 the course total should be 74, if it is 2, it should be 74 again and so on, as written above  ...

Comment: as the grade is arbitrary, you can use an associative array to get the final grade from the quiz total. (you can also use a switch statement but it will be less efficient)

Comment: thank you for the help, thats what i had in mind, but I dont know how to use an associative array, could you explain it, please ???

Comment: I want it to be done automatically, not manually by a teacher

Comment: Do you want a PHP solution or are you looking for a SQL query to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you require it to be actual value or just look like it? What I am trying to say is that you may probably be satisfied with standard functionality of [Grade Letters](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Grade_letters)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but grade letters cannot help , because I want more than 14 items, and I dont find any option to add more. Any other idea ???